# Fatal error getId() on a non-object called in an array of objects

Tags: arrays, object, foreach, symfony, fatal-error

I have a fatal error (call to getId() on a non-object) in this code :

```
$users[] = $em->getRepository(Tutore::class)->findAll();

foreach ($users as $user) {
        $colle = $em->getRepository(Colle::class)->find($id);
        $passages[] = $em->getRepository(PasserColle::class)->findBy(array('colle' => $colle->getId(),
            'username' => $user->getId()));
}

foreach ($passages as $passage){
        $passages['note'] = $passage->getNote();
}
```

I dumped $users and it's an array of object. I don't understand why it's showing me this error.
I have the same error with $passage->getNote().

Comment: It's an object, but is it the right object? Show some code from the findAll() for example

Comment: It's a doctrine function that finds an array of all objects in the repository.
Tutore Repository extends User Repository. I tried with User Repository but I have the same error.

Comment: and if you dump `$user` in the foreach loop ?

Comment: Beginning of the array :
`array(815) { [0]=> object(PACES\UserBundle\Entity\Tutore)#2221 (41)`

Comment: In which exactly line??

Comment: Error's in line 6 : `$user->getId()`

Comment: So it is normal user is an array and not an object

Comment: if you do `$user = $em->getRepository(Tutore::class)->findAll();` 
 instead of `$user[] = $em->getRepository(Tutore::class)->findAll();`

Comment: That could be the reason, if you do $user[]  = .. , you are creating an array  and putting in the first position the result of the query (other array). Try what @DOZ say. The same apply for  $passages[].

Comment: Your answer worked. Thank you very much.

To finish this function, I need to create array $passage[$i]['note'] but I have another fatal error : 'cannot use object of type PasserColle as array'.

How can I create this array ?

Answer (score 1):

**First issue**

Do

```
$users = $em->getRepository(Tutore::class)->findAll();
```

Instead of

```
$users[] = $em->getRepository(Tutore::class)->findAll();
```

**Second issue**

Try this :

```
$newArray = []; 

foreach ($passages as $key => $passage){
    $newArray[$key]['note'] = $passage->getNote();
}
```